# how to use ProgressRing in a WPF application for windows

Tags: wpf, xaml, controls

As simple as in the title, I'd like to know how to use a ProgressRing on my gui. I can't figure out how to import the Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls namespace in which seems to be located.
Thanks!

Eugenio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can add a reference to a Windows Store Apps DLL to a WPF project, they are built against different versions of the framework.

You could however use a ProgressRing from a different WPF targeting DLL; MahApps Metro has one https://mahapps.com/docs/controls/progressring (source is on github so you can just take what is needed without having to jump fully into the metro style)

Or you could implement your own following a tutorial http://henryzhu1997.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/creating-a-progressring-for-wpf/